# Reducir lineas de codigo de un `if return true`

Tags: php, condiciones

Recuerdo haber visto esto en algun lado. Que cuando tienes una sentencia `if` solo para devolver `true` o `false` entonces hay una forma de acortar el codigo. Es codigo de PHP...

Tengo esta sentencia

```
if ($count > 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Bien, se que no parece gran cosa, pero creo que son muchas lineas de codigo solo para saber si es `0` o `mayor que 0`.

Recuerdo haber visto un video especificamente sobre este caso, pero en Js, si mal no recuerdo, que cuando tienes un `if` solo para verificar si es true o false, sin nada mas de codigo dentro, habia una forma de simplicarlo y que se vuelva solo una linea. (No me refiero a poner todo el codigo en una sola linea, sino especificamente reducir todo.

Comment: Puedes obviar el else, es decir, está de más escribirlo. Coloca el `return false` inmediatamente después de la llave de cierre del if. Otra opción es usar una [condición ternaria](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) para reducir el `if-else`.

Comment: Eso era, la condicion ternaria! Se me habia olvidado. Muchas gracias, ahora podre deshacerme de tantos `if-else`

Comment: No vendría mal una lectura al apartado [*Operadores de comparación*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) en el Manual de PHP. Para este caso concreto sobran incluso los ternarios. **El operador `>` devuelve ya `true` o `false`** según el caso, por tanto puedes devolver directamente el resultado de esa comparación, como bien explica @LordXedriantheHigger en su respuesta.

Comment: Una alternativa adicional a las propuestas puede ser en una sola linea quitando llaves: `if($count>0) return true; else return false;`

Answer (score 3):

En este caso basta con decir:

```
return $count > 0;
```

Y si quieres retornar valores diferentes a true o false en una sola línea, puedes usar algo que se conoce como operador ternario:

```
return $count > 0 ? 'Es verdadero' : 'Es falso';
```

Los ternarios no solo se limitan a un return:

```
$count > 0 ? HacerEstoSiEsTrue () : HacerEstoSiEsFalse ();
```

Puedes buscar más información acerca de los operadores ternarios.